# Overriding `background-image` with a smaller image for smaller devices in css, will save bandwidth or reduce loading time?

Tags: css, media-queries, pageload

Let's say I did this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1366px)
    .someBg {
         background-image: url('someBg_BIG.jpg');
    }
}
```

Now override the background image like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
    .someBg {
         background-image: url('someBg_SMALL.jpg');
    }
}
```

**Question:** For devices below 480px - Will the css first override the class then **load only** the overridden image? Or will it first **load both** the images and then decide which one will have more precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `@media` only appropriate images will be loaded.
If resolution more than `768px` (for example) only one image will be loaded. If resolution less than `768px` only one image will be loaded too. But if you resize window from `800px` to `500px` both images will be loaded.
You can check it in Chrome inspector.

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  content:url("http://mnprogressiveproject.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/kitten.jpg");
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  img {
    content:url("http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/34800000/Kittens-3-animals-34865509-1680-1050.jpg");
  }
}
```

```html
<img alt="">
```

Comment: Checked. A very good point indeed. I should would be marking you correct right now if it was a solution based question. As it is more of a query, I will wait for an hour before marking you correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are using css `@media` queries which is used just to change styles according to screen size it doesn't effect anything to load.

So here if you use this css then both the images will load first and then show according to screen size.

Comment: I understand CSS `@media` queries doesn't do anything to load an image. Browsers do. Browser also compiles the CSS and render a page. So why doesn't it decides before hand which image to load?

Comment: for that we need to use different method we need to tell browser always what we want browser to do but with this `@media` browser dont understant we need this load thing.

Comment: Check the answer by @3rdthemagical. I verified too. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

the css:

```css
.somebg{
 max-width: 1400px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.somebg img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

and in html: 
`<div class="somebg"><img src="URL HERE"></div>`

Comment: You didn't understand my question here. I don't need a solution. I have queries I am seeking answers for. Thanks anyway.